# WCF interprocess communication

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two applications that need to talk to each other. I have implemented a WCF service in each application, both opening channels to receive requests from the other. Trouble is, when both channels are open, I get an "There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost that could accept the message" exception.

If I open just one of them, then they both work. How can I implement bi-directional WCF, or at least allow both apps to at as servers and clients?

Mark

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows confusion and leaves me even more confused. First step: what exactly are you trying to? Do you want two applications to communicate? Then in general you need a 'server' and a 'client'. Using duplex communication, both parties can issue a message to the other, without the need for request-response (like HTTP).

So let the first application to start up act as a server, and the other(s) as client. To act as a client you can use a Service Reference, a strongly-typed WCF client.

Comment: Thanks for your repsonse and sorry to confuse you! I have two applications, and in each I create a server to be called by the other. Can you please provide an example of where a server makes a call to the client? I'm not sure how to do this. The clients each call their server at different times in the running of the application.

Comment: If you try to split up your problem in smaller parts, you'll see there's an answer for any of them, e.g. [WCF - calling back to client (duplex ?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735079/wcf-calling-back-to-client-duplex). :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may implement a server in each app. They *must* listen on different endpoints (different identifiers) though. Then each app needs to have a client that connects the server in the other app.

This way both apps can be implemented similarly but are independent. In fact, you could create one single assembly that has both server/client and configure the endpoints by means of application configuration (app.config).

Whether it would be better to use one server/one client should depend on the actual task of the apps. If they are equal, it would be hard to tell who's the server, who's the client.